# meteor template: parse html content

Tags: javascript, meteor

I saved some HTML-content in my collection. By using IronRouter `data()` will be used to set the cursor/array. In this example I just show an example array.

Now the HTML-content isn't shown correctly, as it doesn't get parsed. The user would see the HTML-tags. What do I have to do to get the content displayed correctly?

**IronRouter**

```
Router.route('/article/:_id', {
    name: 'article',
    data: function () {
        var articles = [{ title: 'title', content: '<strong>content</strong>'}];
        return { articles: articles };
    }
});
```

**template**

```
<template name="article">
    {{#each articles}}
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <section>{{content}}</section>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Handlebars triple-stash](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping):

```
<template name="article">
  {{#each articles}}
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <section>{{{description}}}</section>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```